# Create ng-click button in treant.js diagram

Tags: angularjs, button, graph, tree, click

I'm creating a knock-off tournament diagram like this (names are randomly created):
[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chjTC.png)

to create the graph I create the input for Treant thanks to java-script in my angularJS file:

```
/*
    Returns the HTML representing a match
*/
var populateGraphCell = function(match) {
    var content = "";
    if(match.registration_1 != undefined) {
        content += registration_to_html(match.registration_1);
    } else {
        content += "<button ng-click='bonjour()'>Add registration 1</button>";
    }
    content += "<br />";
    if(match.registration_2 != undefined) {
        content += registration_to_html(match.registration_2);
    } else {
        content += "<button>Add registration 2</button>";
    }
    content += "<br />";
    if(match.court != undefined) {
        content += court_to_html(match.court);
    } else {
        content += "<button>Add court</button>";
    }
    return content;
}
$scope.bonjour = function() {
    console.log("hello")
}
```

but i was wondering if there is a way to use ng-click?, in google chrome debug mode, I can see the ng-click element, but when i click on it, nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because angular must compile it. You could use something like this to compile it:

```
$timeout(function () {
    var element = $("your element id or class here");
    $compile(element)($scope)
});
```

Here is a plunker showing it for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/ctcpBpg8YOhlnxPXRBB1?p=preview

BTW, this is not a good practice. You shouldn't be manipulating your DOM objects. That is one of the reasons why AngularJS exists. You could create some type of directive.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm trying to do like that. But could you please explain a little how I should do in order to use a directive here ?

Comment: Could you explain better what you want? I would recomend to open a new issue because it is a complete different question.

Comment: You said that it was better to do it by creating some type of directive but I don't really understand how I should do it

Comment: ok but could you explain better the whole of your code? For example, how is populateGraphCell being called?

Comment: The aim of this graph is to represent a tennis tournament. So we receive element from a backend (in Django) and we translate it in a readable format for Treant.js in javascript. Then we create the treant object. Each "cell" is populate like that: http://pastebin.com/BL722T6f